# Get object property name

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following objects:

```
var Something= {
    "None" : 0,
    "2D" : 1,
    "3D" : 2,
    "4D" : 3,
    "5D" : 4,
    "6D" : 5,
    "7D" : 6
};

function SomethingElse(obj) {

    this.2D = 0;
    this.3D = 0;
    this.4D = 0;
    this.5D = 0;
    this.6D = 0;
    this.7D = 0;

    for (var prop in obj) {
        this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}
```

I have an integer from which I want to get the propertyName of `Something` (for example, if  I pass in 2 I should get back the string "3D". How do I do that?

Eventually I want to use that to set the value of `SomethingElse[propertyName] = 0;`

Comment: just iterate the object and if `object[prop] === param` return `prop`

Comment: So you want to look up the property name given a property value? What if more than one property has the same value?

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be to create a function that iterates with for (... in ...) through all properties of Something and returns the first matching property or else *null*.

```
function search(value)
{
    for (var prop in Something) {
        if (Something[prop] === value) {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```